# ''TO'' / object vs subject - meaning confusion

Tags: grammar

This is the point that  confuses me;

1)How a family built their home to look like a ship - and it's now worth £3.5m

2)I cleaned my house to look clean

structures of the sentences are completely same

but,
in first sentence ''to'' refers to ***object*** of the sentence ***(ship)*** , in the second sentence it refers to the ***subject*** of the senetnce ***(I)*** 
and the meaning becomes completely different

Comment: Your first example is not a sentence, but a subordinate clause. That aside, "to" is a subordinator introducing the clause "to look like a ship", where "ship" is not 'object of the sentence, but complement of the adjective "like". In your second example, "to" is again a subordinator introducing the clause "to look clean". The subordinate clauses "to look like a ship" and "to look clean" function respectively as result and purpose adjuncts.

Comment: @BillJ Are they really correct examples? I mean both are strange. In both the cases it's the subject that *looks like a ship* and *looks clean*. Am I wrong?

Comment: The meaning is actually almost the same - in both cases, **to** means something like "for the purpose of".

Comment: @Man_From_India They are indeed strange. The first example is not even a sentence, and the second, although grammatically OK, is unnatural. In the second, "I" is the subject of the main clause, and "my house" is the _understood_ subject of "to look clean".

Comment: If you want to compare “built their home to look like a ship” with “cleaned my house to look clean” why not stick with those wordings, please?

The original structures of what you were first looking at might have been the same. The posted examples are clearly very different.